# Show current div sidebar

Tags: html, css

a customer want this little thing on his Webseite.
But i have no idea how this thing is called...

it showes the current div on a fixed sidebar

Can someone help?

best regards

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILjNH.jpg

Comment: Can you share the URL where your customer saw this?

Answer (score 1):

it's called ScrollSpy.
i guess [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp) could be helpful.